# Getting big data unnecessarily while using orderbychild() from Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an app that has a video and an article feed. I implemented swipe refresh layout. Whenever user swipes it, it loads last 5 video datas from Firebase.

My database is like this (it's not much data) =>
[image: Database Schema]

Swipe refresh layout listener =>

```
 mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(() -> {
        manager.scrollToPosition(0);
        refreshVideoFeed();

    });
```

And refreshVideoFeed method triggers this =>

```
 Query query = myRef.orderByChild("videoDate").limitToLast(5);

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              ..................
```

It works fine. However, I realized that app is using lots of data when i looked at Realtime Database dashboard (even app is not in product)

[image: Database Usage from 2 clients]

Then I opened Profiler in Android Studio to see what is going on. I ordered by child 'videoDate' and got last 5 videos. It costs 76 KB for refreshing video feed.

[image]

Then again I ordered by child 'videoDate' and got last 20 videos. Again it costs 77KB !

[image]

Also, I implemented the same mechanism for article feed. I have 236 articles in my realtime database. Whenever user swipes, it loads 10 articles and it costs 3,6 MB!

[image]

I wonder why this is happening and how to avoid that. It seems Firebase SDK fetchs all Videos to client and then filters them. But I want to fetch only specific range of data that I specified.

Comment: In your security rules, did you [define an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) on `videoDate`? Without that, all data under `myRef` will be transferred to the client and filtered there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordering and filtering data is only done on the Firebase servers if there's an index defined on the property/value you filter on. If there's no index, the server sends all data to the client, which then orders and filters it. There should a quite explicit message in the log output when this happens.

To [define an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data), you go to the [security rules panel](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/rules) in your Firebase console and on the node that `myRef` points to add an `.indexOn` property. Say `myRef` refers to `/articles`, it'd look something likeL

```
{
  "rules": {
    "articles": {
      ".indexOn": "videoDate"
    }
  }
}
```

If you order/filter on different properties, you can add multiple indexes:

```
".indexOn": [ "videoDate", "category" ]
```